# Ideal $I=({ X }^{ 2 },2X)$ of $\mathbb Z[X]$ generated by ${ X }^{ 2}$ and $2X$ is not primary.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

> Let $I=({ X }^{ 2 },2X)$ ideal of $\mathbb Z[X]$ generated by ${ X }^{ 2}$ and $2X$. Show that $I$ is not primary.

I tried to find $$\sqrt { I } =\sqrt { ({ X }^{ 2 })+(2X) } =\sqrt { \sqrt { { (X }^{ 2 }) } +\sqrt { (2X) }  } =\sqrt { \sqrt { { (X) }^{ 2 } } +\sqrt { (2X) }  } =\sqrt { (X)+(2X) } =\sqrt { (X) } =(X).$$ It is wrong?

Comment: As you have discovered, there are non-primary ideals whose radical is prime.  For this reason, it is impossible to prove that an ideal is non-primary by calculating its radical.

Comment: The computation of $\sqrt I$ is correct, but there is some work to do in order to show that $I$ is not primary.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to find $\sqrt I$ in order to show that $I$ is not primary. We have $2X\in I$, but $X\notin I$ and $2\notin\sqrt I$.

Answer (score 2):

This is basically the same answer as above, but it sometimes help to think of primary ideals this way:

An ideal $I$ of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is primary if all zero divisors in $R=\mathbb{Z}[x]/I$ are nilpotent.  Let $\overline{2},\overline{x}$ be the images of $2$ and $x$, respectively, in $R$.  Then we have that $\overline{2}\overline{x}=0$, but $\overline{2}^n\neq{}0$ for any $n\geq{}0$.

Therefore we have a zero-divisor that is not nilpotent, which means $I$ is not primary.